# Cant save excel spread sheet in openpyxl - Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I can't save the active file I'm working in when I'm in openpyxl.

```
wb_obj =  load_workbook(filename="C:\\Users\\timde\PycharmProjects\\starshipit\\test.xlsx", read_only=False)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
sheet_obj.cell(row=2, column=10).value = 500
wb_obj.save("test.xlsx")
```

I get this error back

```
 File "C:/Users/timde/PycharmProjects/starshipit/writeback_to_sheet.py", line 22, in <module>
    write_back()
  File "C:/Users/timde/PycharmProjects/starshipit/writeback_to_sheet.py", line 15, in write_back
    wb_obj.save("test.xlsx")
  File "C:\Users\timde\PycharmProjects\starshipit\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 392, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\timde\PycharmProjects\starshipit\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 291, in save_workbook
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'w', ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)
  File "C:\Users\timde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test.xlsx'
```

But if I change the file name to test1.xlsx It creates a new file and saves it for me.

So the issue is only saving the current workbook I am in as itself

Thank you all in advance. Much appreciated

Comment: You probably have the file open in excel. Windows applications generally lock the file when opening. If that's the case and closing the file in excel works, I'll post a detailed answer for you to accept.

Comment: Hi there, yes that was it.  Thanks a lot.
Sorry about such an easy question - I'm pretty very new to this. I appreciate your help

Comment: No problem. Will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

MS Office applications generally write-lock the files that they open. Since you have your workbook open in Excel, Python will not be able to open the same workbook. This manifests itself as the `PermissionError` that you are seeing. The simple solution is to close the file in Excel when you want to use it elsewhere.